# Entity framework, отложенный Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте, есть у меня один вопрос : как можно подгружать данные не из таблиц `DbContext` класса ? Мне нужно вызвать подгрузку данных не перед запросом, как это делается обычно ( ex. `db.Users.Include( ... )` ), а после запроса, который отсеивает много данных, как раз из той коллекции отфильтрованных данных.

Дальше эта коллекция перебирается в цикле и для каждой строки отдельно мне приходится подгружать необх. данные (с помощью того же `lazy loading`).Но строк много и нагружать сервер таким кол-вом запросов неправильно. Можно, конечно, сразу подгрузить данные `Includ`-ом в самом начале, но тогда тогда будет слишком много ненужных данных. В общем, вопрос в том как в EF написать следующий аналог SQL запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
FROM T WHERE ... (отсеиваем данные))
as T2 ON T1.A = T2.A (подгружаем данные к отфильтрованной коллекции)
```

**Upd**. Приведу пример, чтобы было нагляднее.Есть к примеру след. код на C#:

```
DbQuery<User> query = db.Users.Where(x => x.Login == "Name") as DbQuery<User>;
User[] users = query.Include(x => x.Profile).ToArray();
```

Здесь я сначала делаю выборку по имени пользователя, а потом подгружаю таблицу Profile.А потом в sql профайлере вижу тот сгенерированный SQL запрос, который выполняется на второй строке:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Profiles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProfileID] = [Extent2].[ProfileID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Profiles] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ProfileID] = [Extent3].[ProfileID]
WHERE N'User_Name' = [Extent1].[Login]
```

Как видно из этого запроса тут наоборот сначала подгружается таблица `Profile`, а потом делается поиск по логину. Мне же необходимо,чтобы это происходило в обратной последовательности, как в примере выше.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно, наверное, каждую таблицу напрямую джойнить, но хотелось бы что-то более удобное

Comment: А вообще может я туплю и в том последнем запросе приоритет сначала отдается условию, а потом join.Вот тут вроде(3 абзац), говорится,что вообще где бы ни стоял Include главный приоритет отдается Where
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900125/where-in-the-call-chain-should-include-ef-linq-extension-be-positioned
Но хотелось бы, конечно, подтверждение от кого-то услышать

Comment: попробуй вместо Where использовать FirstOrDefault тебе все равно я так понял всего одну запись нужно получать

User user=db.Users.FirtsOrDefault(x => x.Login == "Name");
а затем обращаться к навигационному свойтву полученного юзера

Comment: Увы, к сожалению, нет, это был выдуманный пример. В реальности там таблица с ~55000 строк и добрая половина там лишняя. Я бы сам не стал  из-за нескольких миллисекунд сек все это затевать.Но там запрос на 15 сек. идет.Причем как раз 5-10 сек, уходит на подгрузку.

Comment: @nvse, все правильно. оптимизатор сервера принимает решения, основываясь на имеющейся у него статистике. если статистика говорит, что выгодно сначала наложить условие на Login, то первым будет производиться фильтр, а к результатам будут приджойниваться другие таблицы. при правильном наборе индексов ваш запрос должен выполняться менее секунды, выдача результатов будет ограничена пропускной способностью сети.

в вашем запросе вижу подозрительный внешний джойн с Extent3, который мне непонятен - возможно у вас не хватает индексов. можно попросить вас привести список выбираемого этим запросом?